# Classes generated by QueryDSL/APT and static imports

Tags: java, maven, apt, querydsl

Apparently I can't use classes generated with APT in unit tests that use static imports. (Maven sample project can be downloaded [here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-4402735/apt-bug.tar.gz.html))

If the following sample class

```
import com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;

public class UserStore {

    public void something() {
        new JPAQuery(null).from(QUser.user).list(QUser.user.login);
    }

}
```

is changed to

```
import static something.QUser.user;
import com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;

public class UserStore {

    public void something() {
        new JPAQuery(null).from(user).list(user.login);
    }

}
```

the build process (mvn clean install) will fail:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.466s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 30 16:05:40 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project apt-bug: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
...
```

([full error message](http://pastebin.com/z4CZ2PLn))

Does this mean that I cannot use these generated classes with static import in unit tests or is there a problem in the pom.xml files?

EDIT:

POM file: http://pastebin.com/gvycZmXD

Comment: Can you link the actual error message? You cut it off right before it said why it failed....

Comment: added full error message

Comment: I _believe_ it is a problem with the pom, specifically the dependencies. However, it's difficult to say without seeing the pom itself. Could you perhaps post the pom (or even just the dependencies section)? (of course with your class names obfuscated)

Comment: The pom file is included in the tar file of the Maven sample project.

Answer (score 3):

This might be related https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/158

I have not yet had the time to investigate this.

**Edit**

This has apparently been fixed now in Java 7

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7174857
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7159016

Comment: I think this is the same problem. This appears with both Java 6 and Java 7.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a static wildcard import?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem when using wildcards in the static import statements.

Comment: In eclipse it is sometimes releated to clean and compilation error in other part of the project. So simply copy part of it into smaller project and if it work run maven and check for other maven problems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is located in the static import, cause the error messages says the imported QUser.user is neither a class nor an interface. This looks like the user is just an attribute of the Class QUser which would explain the error message.

```
/home/xxx/apt-bug/src/main/java/something/UserStore.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class QUser
location: package something
import static something.QUser.user;
                       ^
/home/xxx/apt-bug/src/main/java/something/UserStore.java:3: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static something.QUser.user;
^
```