# Apt-maven-plugin is neither generating anything nor giving an error

Tags: maven, eclipse-indigo, querydsl

I have a Maven multi-module project and I want to use QueryDSL and Spring Data JPA with one of the modules. I have followed the instructions on [JPA integration](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.3.0/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration) and added both the maven-apt-plugin and querydsl dependencies to the module's pom. 
Now when I run the build with either *clean install* or with *apt:process* or both, all builds will run fine without any errors, but nothing (no Q-classes) is generated at all.

I am using Eclipse Indigo, btw.

Here are the relevant pom parts:

```
<!-- query dsl apt -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- querydsl core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- query dsl jpa -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The dependency versions are declared in the parent pom.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.9</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the apt execution get logged in the console? Do you run mvn from eclipse or command line? Also which Querydsl version?

Comment: Any update on the situation?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818084/classes-generated-by-querydsl-apt-and-static-imports

Comment: Have you tried the apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3? maven-apt-plugin hasn't been maintained for a few years.

Answer (score -1):

1. First start with simplest working project (in multi project it might be other problems not releated to querydsl, but affecting compilation)
2. Then check in newest java 8 (due to [Classes generated by QueryDSL/APT and static imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818084/classes-generated-by-querydsl-apt-and-static-imports))
3. Check in maven if all is building correctly(not in eclipse, from command line).
4. Then if all works try to integrate it into your project(turn off parts of the projects and observe if problem was solve in eclipse).